# Craft Commerce Order Notifications from customer email and name

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

Quite a specific question from a client on another e-commerce system who would maybe like to move to Craft Commerce. I have used Craft for a few client sites now but not Commerce as of yet.

Basically, when a customer places an order he wants the FROM email address and FROM name to be that of the customer who has placed the order (in the confirmation/notification email/invoice that gets sent to him).  It's basically so that he can group all the emails easily in Outlook.

Bit of a specific question but wondered if anyone can shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to write a small plugin that listened to Commerce's `EVENT_BEFORE_SEND_MAIL` event, so you could override the `from` address of the email to the customer's order.

Comment: Brilliant thanks Brad